# How to obtain the stderr on node-fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

Now that the saveToFile callback param has been deprecated:

```
FfmpegCommand.prototype.saveToFile = function(targetfile, callback) {
    if (callback) {
      this.options.logger.warn('saveToFile callback is deprecated, use \'end\' and \'error\' events instead');
```

I've changed my code from this:

```
new ffmpeg({ source: source })
            .toFormat('ogg')
            .saveToFile(path.normalize(targetFile), function(stdout, stderr) {
                console.log('stdout', stdout);
                console.log('stderr', stderr);
            });
```

to this:

```
new ffmpeg({ source: source })
    .toFormat('ogg')
    .on('end', function() {
        console.log('file has been converted succesfully');
    })
    .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('an error happened: ' + err.message);
    })
    .saveToFile(path.normalize(targetFile));
```

but I don't know how to obtain the stderr that the old code give me as a param (stderr).
I know that I can obtain the error message from the on 'error' event, but I would like to get the stderr to get deeper information about what went wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to move the function with stdout and stderr as an argument to the .on('error') event, like this:

```
    .on('error', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(err.message); //this will likely return "code=1" not really useful
        console.log("stdout:\n" + stdout);
        console.log("stderr:\n" + stderr); //this will contain more detailed debugging info
    })
```

Comment: I noticed a case where both are `undefined`; it happens if `ffmpeg` was killed before generating any output (can happen due to missing libs or similar OS errors).